# HttpExchange GET arrived empty

Tags: java, inputstream, handle, httpserver

I've created a HttpServer based on com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange.
in my handler, impementation of com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler, the method public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) gets an exchange with empty requestBody.
On the server side i'm using:

```
server.createContext("/", new BbHandler());
```

On my Midlet client i'm using:

```
String url = "http://localhost:22334/name=john";
```

Why exchange's requestBody has no data to read?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is that there is no body to be read.  Your provided field is in the URL and would be available in the **getRequestURI()** call on the exchange object (though it probably won't be in the **getQuery()** part of the URI object because it is missing the ? separator the URI would expect for query parms), but nothing in the body.  Most often a **GET** request does not have body contents, a **PUT** or **POST** request would.